# Listening to breakpoints from a different host with Xdebug

Tags: debugging, ember.js, phpstorm, ember-cli, xdebug

I'm building an application in Ember.js and I am debugging the PHP API remotely.  It is working when I enable the cookie for XDebug, set a breakpoint, and then run the code.  The breakpoint hits and I get all the debugger data in my IDE (PHPStorm) correctly.

In order to access the API from Ember, I have to use ember-cli with a proxy.  The XDebug cookie is getting passed through the proxy, but requests that I make through Ember do not hit breakpoints in my IDE.  I think this is due to the fact that XDebug sees the ember-cli request as coming from the remote server, rather than my development machine.  Is there a way for me to get debugging to work for requests that go through the ember-cli proxy?  I have to use the proxy instead of going directly to the API from the browser due to cross site browser security issue (ember-cli is running on port 4200 on the server and the API is on port 80).

I have pydbgpproxy running and PHPStorm is working with that as well, but even though the session for the requests going through ember-cli and the requests going from my machine directly to the API are the same key, I think it's still differentiating between the requesting machine's address.

Thank you!

Comment: What cross issues are you having that you can't debug the php separate?
And have you tried to send the requests from Ember using the XDEBUG and Session query string params?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I realized that I needed to configure the contentSecurityPolicy in environment.js in Ember and then change my PHP API to return the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header by using using nelmio/cors-bundle